# Unique post-id for Wordpress Multisite Network

Tags: plugins, posts, multisite

As the title says, is there any way to make sure that posts from subdomains, in a Multisite Network, can use different ids?

The reason for this, is because I'm using [WP Favorite Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/) plugin, and whenever two(or whatever number of) posts from different subdomains/sites form the network have the same id, when adding one to favorite posts, the other, with the same id, gets added aswell, and vice-verse when removing one.

Basically, as far as I figured out how this plugin works, it adds a `href` to a link inside, for example, on a query of posts, that contains the handler & that post id, something like:

```
<a href="....?wpfpaction=add&amp;postid=1"></a>
```

And if the postid is the same for example on two websites on the network, if I add one, the other gets add aswell, and vice-versa.

I guess this is the expected behavior, given the fact that the posts share the same id, however, I would like to know if there's any solution or workaround, to actually make these ids be different accorss the network.

Thank you

Comment: The correct solution is to include the site ID in the list. Contact the author and ask her to make the plugin multisite compatible.

Comment: @toscho I did take a look on the forum, and there was someone else asking for this issue, but no answear so far(1 year ago). I wonder if something can be changed inside the plugin itself, to make this work.

Comment: @toscho looking through the plugin api, and how that link gets created, I notice that it uses the $post_id to generate the action link; from you knowledge is there anyway to differentiate the post_id from the other post ids used in all blogs? I went back and forward with what you suggested, using get_current_blog_id(), to check on which blog it runs, but the outcome stays the same.

Comment: There are **no** comments in the files, and the plugin doesn't use the regular WP APIs. I cannot say where exactly the code have to be changed, probably on many functions. This would require a major rewrite.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use `$post->guid` instead of `$post->ID`.

NB: guid must be in lowercaps for it to work.

Detailed explanation here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209832/71131

Some additional detail on the purpose of keeping `$post->ID` as a backup in your third-party service: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209833/71131

Comment: NB: 'guid' must be in lowercaps, or else it won't work